# Creating Lists from CSV File in python 2.7 using two different read line commands

Tags: list, python-2.7, csv

I am a newbie at Python 2.7 and used the following code to create the list of observations pulled from a csv file.

```
import csv
data = []
with open(datafile,'rb') as f:
    for row in f:
       g=row
       data.append(g)
```

It produces the following list (after reading the first row):

```
['01/01/2005,01:00,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,3,E,9,3,E,9,8.0,A,7,6.0,A,7,87,A,7,1013,A,7,150,A,7,2.1,A,7,16100,A,7,77777,A,7,1.1,E,8,0.099,F,8,0.160,F,8,0,1,A,7']
```

But when I use the following code to read the csv file and create the list:

```
data = []
with open(datafile,'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f
        data = [row for row in r]
```

I get a list that looks as follows (after reading the first row):

```
['01/01/2005', '01:00', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '3', 'E', '9', '3', 'E', '9', '8.0', 'A', '7', '6.0', 'A', '7', '87', 'A', '7', '1013', 'A', '7', '150', 'A', '7', '2.1', 'A', '7', '16100', 'A', '7', '77777', 'A', '7', '1.1', 'E', '8', '0.099', 'F', '8', '0.160', 'F', '8', '0', '1', 'A', '7']
```

This also appears to be a list (with the key difference being the apostrophes around each item in the list instead of just at the beginning and the end).

Since both appear to be lists, why does the code that uses `data.append` not deliver a similar list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first list has just one single element -- a string holding the entire line, inclusing all the commas.

```
>>> l1 =['01/01/2005,01:00,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,3,E,9,3,E,9,8.0,A,7,6.0,A,7,87,A,7,1013,A,7,150,A,7,2.1,A,7,16100,A,7,77777,A,7,1.1,E,8,0.099,F,8,0.160,F,8,0,1,A,7']
>>> len(l1)
1
```

In your second example, `csv.reader` splits this line into several elements and puts those into the list.

```
>>> l2 = ['01/01/2005', '01:00', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '3', 'E', '9', '3', 'E', '9', '8.0', 'A', '7', '6.0', 'A', '7', '87', 'A', '7', '1013', 'A', '7', '150', 'A', '7', '2.1', 'A', '7', '16100', 'A', '7', '77777', 'A', '7', '1.1', 'E', '8', '0.099', 'F', '8', '0.160', 'F', '8', '0', '1', 'A', '7']
>>> len(l2)
68
```

Also note that the loop in your second example is somewhat odd. I assume that this is not your actual code, since there's a syntax error in it. It should probably rather be:

```
r = csv.reader(f)
for row in r:         # row in r, not row in f
    data.append(row)  # append row to data -> 2d-array of items in rows
```

Comment: Thanks to you for the explanation and the insight. You are correct on the code for the loop. I had a typo.